# Changing div using links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a code which uses links to change divs but when I paste these codes to dreamweaver and open the html file on firefox or google chrome they don't work. they do work flawlessly on fiddle though. help will be appreciated.

Here is my [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YsmVn/44)

firefox
 [image: Screenshot firefox]

google chrome

[image: Screenshot chrome]

CSS / HTML / jQuery / Demo

```js
$(document).ready(

function () {
    // Optional code to hide all divs
    $("div").hide();
    $("#one").show();

    // Show chosen div, and hide all others    
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
    });

});
```

```css
.divstyle {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.liststyle li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click a button to make it visible:
<br />
<br />
<ul class="liststyle">
    <li><a id="one_link" href="#" class="one">One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="two_link" href="#" class="two">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="three_link" href="#" class="three">Three</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="four_link" href="#" class="four">Four</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
<br />
<div class="divstyle" id="one">One</div>
<div class="divstyle" id="two">Two</div>
<div class="divstyle" id="three">Three</div>
<div class="divstyle" id="four">Four</div>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: Check if you have `jQuery` referenced in your project. Check the browsers devtools console if you get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Dreamweaver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Works in FF and Chrome</title>
<style>
.divstyle {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.liststyle li {
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Click a button to make it visible:<br /><br />
<ul class="liststyle">
    <li><a id="one_link" href="#" class="one">One</a></li>
    <li><a id="two_link" href="#" class="two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a id="three_link" href="#" class="three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a id="four_link" href="#" class="four">Four</a></li>
</ul>
<br /><br />
<div class="divstyle" id="one">One</div>
<div class="divstyle" id="two">Two</div>
<div class="divstyle" id="three">Three</div>
<div class="divstyle" id="four">Four</div>
<br/><br/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Optional code to hide all divs
     $("div").hide();
     $("#one").show();
     // Show chosen div, and hide all others    
     $("a").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();    
         $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
     });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works when I create a New HTML File and paste them there but it does not work when I paste the codes on my existing webpage HTML. I have no Idea why, I've copied and pasted every single thing from the CSS / JS / HTML codes... 

http://imgur.com/S7u5uOM,0NI4MNB#1   (code view)
http://imgur.com/S7u5uOM,0NI4MNB#0   (Results)

Answer (score -3):

It seems, that you don't have referenced the jQuery lib in your file. Check this first. Open the console (F12) to check if any errors are thrown.

Comment: if you read I commented with this. Also this shouldn't be a valid answer.